# Adding <referenceBlock name="head.additional"> Magento 2 not working

Tags: magento, magento2

I had these blocks in the frontend layout:

```
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Dfl\Marketplace\Block\Profile" name="marketplace_sellerprofile" template="profile.phtml" cacheable="false" before="-"/>
    </referenceContainer>
    <referenceContainer name="sidebar.main">
        <block class="Dfl\Marketplace\Block\Profile" name="marketplace_sellerprofileleft" template="profile_left_sidebar.phtml" cacheable="false" before="-"/>
    </referenceContainer>
    <referenceContainer name="sidebar.additional">
        <block class="Dfl\Marketplace\Block\Profile" name="marketplace_sellerprofileright" template="profile_right_sidebar.phtml" cacheable="false" before="-"/>
    </referenceContainer>
```

then i wanted to add a new block in order to insert it in the  section.
I added the following command above these blocks

```
    <referenceBlock name="head.additional">
      <block class="Dfl\Marketplace\Block\Profile" name="marketplace_social_tags" template="social_tags.phtml" />
    </referenceBlock>
```

then in my social_tags.phtml template I just added a simple meta entry.

[meta entry example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VyjhV.png)

Then I run **setup:upgrad**e and **setup:static-content:deploy en_US es_ES**
But the entry wasn't there in the head tag. 
I followed these links yet i was unable to display the meta entries.

[Atwix - Adding blocks to the head section in Magento 2](https://www.atwix.com/magento-2/adding-blocks-to-head-section/)

[add-block-in-head-tag-in-magento-2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/147602/add-block-in-head-tag-in-magento-2/147606)

Any help? What it's missing?

Answer (score 3):

Man. I had the same problem while trying to get hreflang things in the head.
Tried for 4 hours.

Even though several sites and even an example module reference the head.additional in the default.xml - I found out, for me it was only working when using

```
<referenceBlock name="head.additional">
```

in the default_head_blocks.xml

That drived me so crazy.